# How do i make a sidebar background color?

Tags: css, sidebar

With the 20-11 theme i would like to make the sidebar one long color. I have no idea how long my page are and i need the sidebar height to be the same as the post height. Right now when i do `#secondary { background-color: green; }` the green is only as long as it needs to be so it is extremely short. How do i get it all the way down?

Comment: Purely CSS questions are not in scope of the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way to create the solid color side bar is with this CSS:

```
#branding { background-color: #ffffff; }
#page { background: #ffffff url(path_to_image) repeat-y; }
```

Replace #ffffff with the appropriate color used in your template (if they are different). The "path_to_image" would need to be pointed to an image file that is 1000px wide and 1px high. The image itself would contain the sidebar color starting about 800px from the left.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. You should never have to use a "1000 by 1px" image.

Comment: @GavinR: Unfortunately out of all the answers i found online (which includes SO and a my own question on SO) this is the only method that works.

Comment: Marking an answer as useful does not make it the "right" answer. My claim is that this method is the "simplest way..." There is indeed a way to accomplish what was asked sans CSS image, but my approach is different and that's the answer I provided. @GavinR, If you believe it is wrong, please feel free to elaborate.